# LINQ join based in interface implemation

Tags: c#, linq, interface

Let's say I have a an interface, which is basically a combination of two sub-interfaces. The idea behind this is, that I have two different API's. One which provides public information on a person. And once which provides the 'secret' information. It could look something like this:

```
public interface IPublicPersonData
{
    // The ID is the key
    int PersonId { get; set; }

    // This property is specific to this part
    string Name {get; set; }
}

public interface ISecretPersonData
{
    // The ID is the key
    int PersonId { get; set; }

    // This property is specific to this part
    decimal AnnualSalary{ get; set; }
}

public interface IPerson: IPublicPersonData, ISecretPersonData
{
    // No new stuff, this is merely a combination of the two. 
}
```

So basically I get two lists. One `List<IPublicPersonData>` and one `List<ISecretPersonData>`. I would like to **join** these into a single `List<IPerson>`, ideally using LINQ.

I cannot really find anything on how control the type of output from LINQ, based on the type of input, even if the logic is there (in the means of interfaces implementing interfaces).

```
public List<IPerson> JoinPersonData(
    List<IPublicPersonData> publicData, 
    List<ISecretPersonData> secretData)
{
    // What the heck goes here?
}
```

Comment: `List<IPublicPersonData>` and `List<ISecretPersonData>` do not contain items of type IPerson, so you cannot just join them and produce a `List<IPerson`, you are essentially trying to do `IPerson person = ISecretPersonData + IPublicPersonData` which isn't valid. I know thats the idea you are trying to model but it isn't that simple

Comment: You need some method that takes an Instance of IPublicPersonData and ISecretPersonData and creates a new concrete implemenation of IPersonData (what class that maybe) and returns it

Comment: If it makes it a lot simpler, it would be okay that the join method returned a `List<Person>` instead (`Person` implements `IPerson` and nothing else).

Comment: But how does the join know how to take an ISecretPersonData and an IPersonData and  create a Person or an IPerson? Just because IPerson implements those two interfaces doens't mean it can just mash them together

Comment: If the ID matches, then we know it is the same person. `IPerson` implements both interfaces, so all properties from the sub-interfaces, also exists i `IPerson`. Or am I wrong?

Comment: I think you've got slight mixed up with your understanding of Polymorphism. IPerson is an ISecretPersonData
IPerson is an IPublicPersonData

IPublicPersonData might be an IPerson
ISecretPersonData might be an IPerson

Comment: Interfaces in C# are *not* duck typed, we don't have the notion of 'can you fullfill the contract of the interface? Yes, then great you'll do'. You can do this in Typescript, but not in C#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say you wrote a method such as:

```
public ISomething CombinePersonWithSecret(
    IPublicPersonData publicPerson, 
    ISecretPersonData secret)
{
    if(publicPerson.PersonId != secret.PersonId)
    {
        throw ...;
    }
    //join 2 params into a single entity
    return something;
}
```

Now you might...

```
IEnumerable<ISomething> secretivePeople = PublicPeople.Join(
    SecretPersonData,
    publicPerson => publicPerson.PersonId,
    secret => secret.PersonId,
    (publicPerson, secret) => CombinePersonWithSecret(publicPerson, secret))
```

Comment: Should ISomething not be IPerson?

Comment: I do like your idea, even though it doesn't use LINQ. Thanks :-).

Comment: @Noceo Sure, it uses LINQ. I just spun out the `CombinePersonWithSecret` method because it isn't clear how much work you need to do in the final selector of the LINQ join statement. You could equally inline all the logic into the selector and drop the `CombinePersonWithSecret` method.

Comment: @Dave That's a choice for the OP. IMO, it might perhaps be a subclass of `IPerson`, but I didn't want to involve myself with that decision.

Comment: I noticed, that I needed to include LINQ, I just didn't realize that those methods where part of the LINQ package :-). Anyway, I got it to work, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not in the Join, it is in the IPerson you want to return. One of the parameters of the Join methods is used what to do with joined result.

You want to join them into a new object that implements `IPerson`. If you already have such an object: great, use that one, if you don't have it, here is an easy one:

```
public PersonData : IPerson // and thus also IPublicPersonData and ISecretPersonData
{
     // this PersonData contains both public and secret data:
     public IPublicPersonData PublicPersonData {get; set;}
     public ISecretPersnData SecretPersonData {get; set;}


     // implementation of IPerson / IPublicPersonData / ISecretPersonData
     int PersonId
     { 
         get {return this.PublicPersonData.Id; }
         set
         {   // update both Ids
             this.PublicPersonData.Id = value;
             this.SecreatPersonData.Id = value;
         }
     }
     public string Name
     {
        get { return this.PublicPersonData.Name; },
        set {this.PublicPersonData.Name = value;}
     }

     public decimal AnnualSalary
     {
         get {return this.SecretPersonData.AnnualSalary;},
         set {this.SecretPersnData.AnnualSalary = value;
     }
}
```

This object requires no copying of the values of the puclic and secret person data. Keep in mind however, if you change values, the original data is changed. If you don't want this, you'll need to copy the data when creating the object

```
IEnumerable<IPublicPersonData> publicData = ...
IEnumerable<ISecretPersonData> secretData = ...

// Join these two sequences on same Id. Return as an IPerson
IEnumerable<IPerson> joinedPerson = publicData       // take the public data
    .Join(secretData,                                // inner join with secret data
    publicPerson => publicPerson.Id,                 // from every public data take the Id
    secretPerson => secretPerson.Id,                 // from every secret data take the Id
    (publicPerson, secretPerson) => new PersonData() // when they match make a new PersonData
    {
         PublicPersonData = publicPerson,
         SecretPersnData = secretPerson,
    });
```

Comment: Very interesting approach. I didn't think of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

LINQ's [Join method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause#inner-join) does the job for you. Assuming there is a `Person : IPerson` class, here is two ways to implement your `JoinPersonData` method:

```
public static IEnumerable<IPerson> LiteralJoinPersonData(List<IPublicPersonData> publics, List<ISecretPersonData> secrets)
{
    return from p in publics
           join s in secrets on p.PersonId equals s.PersonId
           select new Person(p.PersonId, p.Name, s.AnnualSalary);
}

public static IEnumerable<IPerson> FunctionalJoinPersonData(List<IPublicPersonData> publics, List<ISecretPersonData> secrets)
{
    return publics
        .Join<IPublicPersonData, ISecretPersonData, int, IPerson>(
            secrets,
            p => p.PersonId,
            s => s.PersonId,
            (p, s) => new Person(p.PersonId, p.Name, s.AnnualSalary));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, it looks very clean. I will give it a try, and give you an upvote if it works :-)